# Get post id in Post Page within Wp-admin

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to get post ID within Post page. I need this for custom meta box so i can set the id in shortcode. I can show the result in notices but don't know how to make it global to use for meta input. What i got till now is :

```
function foo(){
global $post;
$nid = $post->ID;
var_dump($nid);
}
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'foo' );
```

which show the id but i need it as a variable so i can use it later. so i tried to make `$nid` global then echo it but it show nothing.

Comment: You can put it in a cookie, so you can use it over the whole website.

Comment: I need this for every post(unique id). And i only need this to use within post(wp-admin) as metabox.

Comment: Ah if it's unique every time, a cookie is no option indeed.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress already defines `global $post` and it is fully available where relevant. But you don't need this when creating a meta box, as the object `$post` is passed as a parameter by default:

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_box_so_21755578' );

function add_box_so_21755578() {
    add_meta_box( 
        'box_so_21755578',
        'Post ID',
        'print_box_so_21755578',
        'post',
        'side',
        'high'
    );
}

function print_box_so_21755578( $post )
{
    echo "This post ID is $post->ID";
}
```

[image]